# Terraform modules and relative directory structures

Tags: module, terraform

I am working with a client who has a number of Terraform modules predefined and in many cases, for a given AWS resource type, multiple module types.

So, I am attempting to use one of these modules like so:

```
module "some_s3_bucket" {
  source = "git::https://github.acme.com/tmodules/aws_s3_bucket.git//modules/simple"
  ...
}
```

However, one of the *.tf files in the ./modules/simple directory is called common_bucket.tf and this file contains the single line:

```
../common/bucket.tf
```

So, how I reference the simple module, yet have the Terraform *.tf files be able to reference the relative directory **common**?

Comment: That's a symlink and it sounds like a question for the client rather than the wider internet who can't see the code base.

Comment: The question was directed at those DevOps people who have set up this type of structure in the past and explain how they saw developers who relied on these modules to access them.